# How to generate data from normal distribution

Tags: python-3.x

I need to generate Data set from Normal distribution [image: N]. How to generate this data using Python. The value of [image: mu] and [image: sigma] is given.

Comment: By data do you mean generate *samples* from the normal distribution?

Comment: Yes generate data from normal distribution

Answer (score 8):

Use `numpy.random.normal`

If you want to generate 1000 samples from the standard normal distribution you can simply do

```
import numpy
mu, sigma = 0, 1
samples = numpy.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) for additional details.

Comment: Many thanx @Banach Tarski. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute it manually

```
import numpy as np

mu = 0;
sigma = 1;

# Generates numbers between -0.5, 0.5
x_vals = np.random.rand(10) - 0.5

# Compute normal distribution from x vals
y_vals = np.exp(-pow(mu - x_vals,2)/(2 * pow(sigma, 2))) / (sigma * np.sqrt(2*np.pi))

print y_vals
```

Or you can use the given function

```
# You can also use the randn function
y_vals2 = sigma * np.random.randn(10) + mu

print y_vals2
```

Comment: Thanks @jrhee let me try it.